# kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler - Failed to send requests for topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I've been struggling for days trying to make a really simple application with a kafka broker and a kafka producer running on localhost, I've read all the possible answers to similar problems on google but still I couldn't make it work.

This is the error I get:

```
INFO  kafka.client.ClientUtils$ - Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host:localhost,port:9092 with correlation id 0 for 1 topic(s) Set(clicks)
[ProducerSendThread-] INFO  kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Connected to localhost:9092 for producing
[ProducerSendThread-] INFO  kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Disconnecting from localhost:9092
[ProducerSendThread-] WARN  kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo - Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic clicks -> 
No partition metadata for topic clicks due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [clicks]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException 
[ProducerSendThread-] INFO  kafka.client.ClientUtils$ - Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host:localhost,port:9092 with correlation id 1 for 1 topic(s) Set(clicks)
[ProducerSendThread-] INFO  kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Connected to localhost:9092 for producing
[ProducerSendThread-] INFO  kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Disconnecting from localhost:9092
[ProducerSendThread-] WARN  kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo - Error while fetching metadata [{TopicMetadata for topic clicks -> 
No partition metadata for topic clicks due to kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException}] for topic [clicks]: class kafka.common.LeaderNotAvailableException 
[ProducerSendThread-] ERROR kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler - Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: clicks
[ProducerSendThread-] INFO  kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler - Back off for 100 ms before retrying send. Remaining retries = 3
```

And this is my code:

```
Properties properties= new Properties();
properties.put( "broker.id", "1");
properties.put( "advertised.host.name", "localhost");
properties.put( "advertised.port", "9092");
properties.put( "host.name", "localhost");
properties.put( "auto.create.topics.enable","true");
properties.put("zookeeper.connect", zookeeperConnectString);
properties.put("port","9092");
properties.setProperty("num.partitions", "1");
properties.setProperty("log.dirs", newPath(KAFKA_LOG_DIR).toString());

KafkaConfig kafkaConfig = new KafkaConfig(properties);
KafkaServerStartable kafkaServer = new KafkaServerStartable(kafkaConfig);
kafkaServer.startup();

String topic = clicks;

ZkClient zookeeper = new ZkClient(zookeeperConnectString, 30000, 30000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
if (!AdminUtils.topicExists(zookeeper, topic)) {
   AdminUtils.createTopic(new ZkClient(zookeeperConnectString), topic, 1, 1, new Properties());
    }
zookeeper.close();

Properties producerProps = new Properties();
producerProps.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
producerProps.put("key.serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
producerProps.setProperty("producer.type", "async");
producerProps.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
producerProps.put("request.required.acks","0");

Producer producer = new Producer(new ProducerConfig(producerProps));

String click = "exampleMessage";
producer.send(ImmutableList.of(new KeyedMessage(topic, click)));
producer.close();
```

I already have a zookeeper instance correctly running on localhost:2181.

I'm using the following versions of kafka and zookeeper:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
      <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks for any help or comment :)

Comment: Have you tried getting topic meta info through command line by using _describe_ command? 'bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic clicks'

Comment: I cannot use the kafka command line. However if I access zookeeper with curator I see that a node for the topic has been created: /brokers/topic/cliks. Instead the node /brokers/ids is empty.

Comment: i.e there are no active kafka brokers.  So make sure you have at least one kafka broker is up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody has encountered the same issue, I made it work adding  `Thread.sleep(500);` after the creation of the topic. I don't know exactly why, it may be due to the instance of Zookeeper running on localhost that takes some time to initialize.